# telerik firefox 64 image selector broken wysiwyg editor

Tags: firefox, telerik, radeditor

it seems that with the newest firefox version 64 the image resize option is broken in the telerik wysiwyg editor

it's not longer possible to just select the image and resize it as it is on chrome or firefox versions lower than 64

Screenshots:

[firefox 64](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Lp26.png)

[current chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xInYC.png)

Telerik Demo Page:

https://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/editor/examples/overview/defaultcs.aspx

anyone got an idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

editor.get_document().execCommand("enableObjectResizing",null, true);

editor.get_document().designMode = "on";

when initialising the editor fixed it for me